# Center image and crop it

Tags: image, html, center, hidden, crop

I want to put an image into a div element, which is much smaller than the image and hide or crop image outside div element. I've done this like this one:

```
.slideshow img {
    width: 250px;
}
.slideshow {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 170px;
    width: 250px;
    position:relative;

}
```

it works fine, but I image crops from it's top, but I want to center image and then crop it from top and bottom. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

Use clip property of css for image or set position relative with negative left and top position

```
img 
{
clip:rect(0px,60px,200px,0px);
}
```

Comment: but what if pic will be different sizes? crop is static as I understood right

Comment: change clip values when u change the images

Answer (score 0):

You can only vertically centre an image in a line that is at least as tall as the image. So the trick is to centre the image in a very tall div, and then use relative positioning to centre the div relative to the original div. The CSS you'll need on the inner div is something like `vertical-align: middle; line-height: 850px; position: relative; top: -340px;`.

Answer (score 0):

Just add:

```
position:relative;
left:-25%;
top:-25%;
```

to your .slideshow img class

This should work.